# Smoothing quickly changing current/power draw for easier measurement

Tags: current-measurement, diy, power-measurement, iot

I want to measure the power consumption of an IoT device with LoRa module.

I read quite a few posts about this topic and two issues come up regularly:

1. the high dynamic range needed and
2. the high sampling frequency needed

This question is about the second difficulty.

Is it possible to

1. smooth the current flow from the power supply in a way that a slow multimeter (let's assume 1sps) could give an accurate reading of the current drawn in the last second?
2. If not, would it be possible if I had 1ksps (=cheap MCU)?

If it's not reasonable to do this: are there ways to either smooth the voltage over the sense resistor (like with a low pass filter) or use something like an analog accumulator circuit?

The goal would be to have an affordable device that accurately (+/- 5%) measures current drawn by a DUT so that I can calculate how many years the battery might last. Please assume that the user doesn't have access to a fancy oscilloscope.

Comment: Do you know how T=RC works? or coulomb counters work?

Comment: Thanks for the keywords. T=RC I do understand now, but it's not clear to me what application you have in mind. I looked at three coulomb counters (DS2740, LTC2941 and LTC2959). The first two don't have the necessary resolution but the third one might work and solve my problem entirely.